# Unable to access WordPress admin dashboard

Tags: wordpress, http, http-status-code-404

I was trying to redirect the site from http to https and first installed the easy https redirection plugin. Then I went to general and changed the permalinks from http to https. Then upon trying to access the dashboard, it now reads

Not Found

The requested URL /wp-admin/customize.php was not found on this server.

I have a backup on my computer from backupguard plugin, but how do I restore it?

I'm still new to coding and I don't have WordPress installed on my computer yet. Sorry

Comment: Same issue here, did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

First uninstall the easy https redirection plugin. Then after change permalink from http to https in general settings.

Comment: How do I uninstall and change the permalink if I can't access the dashboard though?

Comment: Go to your theme folder. Open functions.php file and write <?php ob_start(); ?> at the top of file.

Comment: Sorry but where do I access the theme folder?

Comment: I have my FTP credentials but I;m still confused on how to access it with FTP clients

Comment: Open FTP. Go to wp-content->themes->your theme folder.

Comment: Are you use filezilla? If yes then read documentation here: https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Documentation

Comment: Yeah, so far Connection attempt failed with "EAI_NONAME - Neither nodename nor servname provided, or not known"

Comment: If you have issue of connection then user port in FTP. Otherwise go to file menu click on site manager and enter detail and try to connect.

Comment: details are correct as far as I know but still the same error. For the wordpress site, media and admin dashboard is now inaccessible. Any attempt to edit the site results in the error 404 in the question.